# Batch file to count files matching first 6 characters in file name and output file group and its count

Tags: batch-file

I would like to have a batch file to count all file names with common prefix and output the file group and its count. I have these files in a directory:

- A1110601.zip
- A1110602.zip
- A1110603.zip
- A1120601.zip
- A1120602.zip

I want to group the first 3 by `A11106*.zip` and the last two by `A11206*.zip`.

My desired output is:

```
A11106: 3
A11206: 2
```

I have tried to copy sample codes from the forum, but they don't fulfilled my desired output.

Here is the code I have so far. But the output is not as described above.

```
@echo off
title Store Data Counter
:recurse
set I=1
echo "files counter"

FOR /f "tokens=*" %%A IN ('dir /a-d /b "Z:\StoreData\A11106*.zip"') do (call :showfiles "%%A")
echo A111: %I%

FOR /f "tokens=1" %%A IN ('dir /a-d /b "Z:\StoreData\A11206*.zip"') do (call :showfiles "%%A")
echo A112: %I%

pause
goto :eof

:showfiles
echo %1
set /a I+=1
goto :eof
```

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own so far? please show your efforts! How do you know what part is considered as the prefix? is it always 6 characters long as your examples show? or is it everything but the last two characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a batch code for this task.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
for %%I in ("*.zip") do call :CountFile "%%~nI"
for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=#=" %%I in ('set Group# 2^>nul') do echo %%I: %%J
endlocal
goto :EOF

:CountFile
set "FileName=%~1"
set "FileGroup=%FileName:~0,6%"
if "Group#%FileGroup%" == "" (
    set "Group#%FileGroup%=1"
) else (
    set /A Group#%FileGroup%+=1
)
goto :EOF
```

`"*.zip"` can be extended with full path to the ZIP files to count.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

And read also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul` used here to redirect the error message output by command **SET** from **STDERR** to device **NUL** to suppress it in case of no *.zip file could be found at all.

The redirection operator `>` must be escaped here with `^` to be interpreted on executing command **SET** and not on parsing the **FOR** command line. Otherwise `2>nul` without `^` would be interpreted as redirection for command **FOR** defined at an invalid position in the command line which would result in a batch execution exit because of a syntax error.

Comment: Hi Mofi! Great! It was all I needed. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

The following batch script should do what you want -- let us call it `mask-count.bat`:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

:LOOP
set "MASK=%~1"
if defined MASK (
    call :SUB "%~1"
    shift /1
    goto :LOOP
)

endlocal
exit /B


:SUB
set "ARG=%~1"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "NUMF=0"
for /F "skip=4 tokens=1" %%L in ('
    2^> nul dir /A:-D /N /-C "!ARG!"
') do (
    set "NUMF=!NUMD!"
    set "NUMD=%%L"
)
echo(!ARG!: %NUMF%
endlocal
exit /B
```

To use this script, provide the applicable file masks as command line arguments; for instance:

```
mask-count.bat "A11106*.zip" "A11206*.zip"
```

This would lead to the following output when applied to your directory:

> ```
> A11106*.zip: 3
> A11206*.zip: 2
> ```